# What's an easy way to open an activerecord source code referenced from a gem's failed rspec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems

Supposed I have an error such as when I run the rspec test of a gem:

```
/home/sally/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@obfuscate_id/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:515:in `table_structure'
```

What's an easy way to open the activerecord-4.1.7 source code in my favorite text editor such as vim or sublime?

Comment: vim /home/sally/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@obfuscate_id/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use: 
 `bundle open activerecord`

[Documentation for `bundle open`](http://bundler.io/v1.6/bundle_open.html)

> Opens the source directory of the provided GEM in your editor. For this to work the `EDITOR` or `BUNDLER_EDITOR` environment variable has to be set.